# How to represent functions values Table in a form of columns with arguments and values?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, arguments

Evaluating `MatrixForm[Table[10 i + j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}]]` gives me a 4x3 matrix, as seen [in example](https://wolfram.com/xid/0gisaa-nux), representing function's values. How can I transform this table in a table like this?

```
i j  f[i,j]
1 1   11
1 2   12
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TableForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html):

```
TableForm[Join @@ Table[{i, j, 10 i + j}, {i, 4}, {j, 3}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {i, j, f[i, j]}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

or replace `TableForm` with `MatrixForm` to get:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use  [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html):

```
Grid[Prepend[Join @@ Table[{i, j, 10 i + j}, {i, 4}, {j, 3}], {i, j, f[i, j]}], 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: But it is still the values of a function! For example, in the first row, when `i=11` and `j=12` the third column should hold value `10*11+12=122`, not 13

Comment: @Olga, please see the corrected version.